# SharePoint 2010 Add new item link disappears with broken inheritance

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, permissions, folder, inheritance

Hello Stackexchange SharePoint masters :)

I've been a long time reader of this marvelous source of information but at long last I could not find a solution to a problem I encountered so I figured it would be time to post my first question:

I have a document library, and have 3 groups that should have access to contribute to one of the 3 folders in the document library. So group 1 should have contribute access to Folder 1, group two to folder 2, etc. while having no access at all to each others folders, as well as no ability to place documents in the root of the document library. (read access only on the library itself)

So after configuring the library with broken inheritances, only contribute access for the groups on their respective folders, and read only to the top level of the document library. This works except for one detail:

The add new item link at the bottom of the library webpart is removed completely, which is desirable on the top level of the library, but not in the folders where the users need to upload their documents. They can still upload via the ribbon, but the majority of the users insist to have this link at the bottom of the library.

So my question to you is if there is a way to bring this button back, or if this is one of those annoying sharepoint 2010 quirks that is not removable?

I am working in a Sandboxed Site collection, with restrictions on the uploading of sandboxed solutions in place so the only way around this for me is most likely javascript or css. There will be hundreds of folders in the long run, along with hundreds of user groups so finding an effective way to un-hide the standard add new item button and not using C# is required, but it seems to be beyond me to achieve this. Has anyone encountered this before and found a solution?

Comment: Is the add new item link not visible to the site collection admin as well ?

Comment: As site collection admin, or anyone with contribute access to the library itself the button remains visible and functions properly. It is merely for the bulk of the users with contribute access only to the folders, and read access to the top level of the library.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description of desired functionality you would be better of creating 3 libraries with unique permissions set in each one. This way the users of library 1 will have contribute access to library one and will see the add document button, but others will only have read permission in the library and will not see the add document button.

Alternatively you can create a web part that you place at the bottom of the page that would generate the add document (and any other links that you may want) based on whatever criteria that are desirable (such as whether current user has permission to upload documents in this place).

Comment: Hi Eugene, thank you for your input! Unfortunately making 200 document libraries is not something I would like to do since it will make navigation of the site a little tricky :) We are trying to solve this with the content organizer instead, as it is better as a uploading mechanism.